# Why do C# enum types not need to be declared static when used in a static method?

Tags: c#, variables, enums, static

This is my first post and I look forward to joining this community.

I was initially having issues with my code compiling.  I had a static method that called on conversion values inside of a dictionary.  After some research I learned that not only methods need to be declared static, but also variables.

What perplexed me is that the enum for the Pressur.Unit type does not need to be declared static.  I have played with some other variables such as double and int type, and it seems that they must also be called static to be used within the static method.

Can anyone explain to me exactly what is special about the enum type that allows it to work without being called static?  Actually, when adding static to the declaration it also creates a compilation error.

This is a snapshot of my code:

```
public class Pressure
    {
        public enum Unit
        {
            psi,
            psf,

            mPa,
            Pa,
            hPa,
            kPa,
            MPa,

            mmH2O,
            mH2O,
            inH2O,
            ftH2O,

            mmHg,
            inHg,

            atm,
            bar,

            kgcm2            
        }


        // Conversions for each unit to/from Pa
        private static readonly Dictionary<Unit, double> conversions = new Dictionary<Unit, double>()
        {
            { Unit.psi, 6894.76 },
            { Unit.psf, 47.9 },

            { Unit.mPa, 0.001 },
            { Unit.Pa, 1 },
            { Unit.hPa, 100 },
            { Unit.kPa, 1000 },
            { Unit.MPa, 1000000 },

            { Unit.mmH2O, 9.80665 },
            { Unit.mH2O, 980.665 },
            { Unit.inH2O, 248.84 },
            { Unit.ftH2O, 2986.08 },

            { Unit.mmHg, 133.322 },
            { Unit.inHg, 3386.39 },

            { Unit.atm, 101325 },
            { Unit.bar, 100 },

            { Unit.kgcm2,  98068} 
        };


        /// <summary>
        /// Converts pressure between engineering units.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">Pressure value</param>
        /// <param name="unitIn">Pressure unit of input value</param>
        /// <param name="unitOut">Pressure unit of returned value</param>
        /// <returns>Pressure value in the output pressure unit.</returns>
        public static double Convert(double value, Unit unitIn, Unit unitOut)
        {
            return value * conversions[unitIn] / conversions[unitOut];
        }
    }
```

I am currently using Visual Studio 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem, because you're never accessing a non-static member of type `Unit`.

You're only accessing an enumeration member, which in this case isn't really different from a constant.

Consider it this way:

- When using such an enumeration member, the compiler knows exactly which value to pick, because there's only one (the definition is essentially static).
- When trying to access a non-static member variable, the compiler won't know which instance/object's member you'd like to access.

Here's a different class to better visualize this:

```
class Person {
    enum Gender {
        Man, Woman, Thing
    };

    Gender gender;
    string name;
}
```

You can use `Gender.Man` and the others at any time, because it's just a definition, not a member or property of a `Person`.

At any time you can ask "What is a `Man`?" And you know the answer, because it's just a definition.

But now try to ask "What is the `gender`?" You can't answer this without knowing which `Person`, because it's a non-static member variable.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

That's because an Enum is a type that is only an enumeration of constants.

To use the Enum you still need an instance of it, in which case, that instance can be static.

```
 public enum Unit
    {
        psi,
        psf,

        mPa,
        Pa,
        hPa,
        kPa,
        MPa,

        mmH2O,
        mH2O,
        inH2O,
        ftH2O,

        mmHg,
        inHg,

        atm,
        bar,

        kgcm2
    }

    public static Unit MyUnit { get; set; } = Unit.hPa;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am a little confused when you say you still need an instance of the enum.  In my code, I don't see any instance of it.  Or is it automatically instantiated when the namespace is called?

Comment: Well, look at it as if the Enum is automatically static in itself exposing just a list of constants.  There's more to it but for simplicity sake I'd go with that.  For example... The way you're using it, from what I see here, is no different than making a class will of constants. Then you're just calling the class . constant name ex:  MyClass { public const int psi } ... var value = MyClass.psi;  I wish you could put code in comments.

Comment: Is this a proper use of enum?  Thanks very much.

Comment: You're a programmer so as long as it works no one is to tell you what's proper and what isn't.  However; the guided answer is probably no.  You should declare you enum in the namespace outside of the class and then reference it from within using a field or property.

Comment: Here's Microsoft's explanation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Ah I see, the reason I didn't is that this namespace has other types of measurements.  Like I will have Pressure.Unit.XXX and Temperature.Unit.XXX and I figured this makes it much more useful in code.

Comment: There you go. A legitimate reason if you ask me.  So if you need to store the state of an enum just make a field or property in your class as well.  public Unit SelectedUnit = Unit.hPa;

Answer (score 0):

conversions is a variable, it must be declared static if you'll be calling it from a static method.

The reason is that non static variables/methods belong to a certain instance of the class, static variables/methods do not, they're just a static part of the class (i.e. you can call them without instantiating the class).

Unit is not a variable nor a method, it is a type so it's not bound to a specific instance anyway.

The fact that the enum is defined inside the class makes it [nested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx) meaning that you must reference the class that contains it in order to use it but it doesn't change the fact that it's not bound to any instance.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that enum was not considered a variable.  My understanding is that enum is like a group of constants.  Is this correct?

Comment: @FrankPereny Enum, like class and struct (int, double, boolean, char, ...) is a type.
Variable != Type, variables hold values, variables can be of certain type, variable of type int, variable of type string, variable of type Unit, ...

Yes, Enum is a group of named constants,
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to upvote all of your answers but I don't have the ability yet.

Comment: @FrankPereny don't sweat it :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `conversions` is a static variable containing an *instance* of an object. Thus,

```
{ Unit.psi, 6894.76 },
{ Unit.psf, 47.9 },
{ Unit.mPa, 0.001 },
// ...
```

are just ordinary entries in a dictionary.

At risk of oversimplification, `enum` is a [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx), not an actual instance of anything. (Note: the "underlying" type of an `enum` is an `int`). Types don't need to be static in order to be used in static variables and methods; for example, your static variable is of type `Dictionary`, which is definitely *not* static.

If it's helpful, when you do something like `Unit.mPa`, think of it more as a constant than as retrieving an actual instance. Indeed, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) defines an enum as "...a distinct type that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list."

My point being that the only thing here that really makes sense to be static is the variable and the method. Obviously, too, if the method is static, the variable must be static too (although the converse isn't true; you can call a static variable from an instance method).

Hopefully, this clarifies things a little (if not please feel free to comment so I can edit).

Comment: Thank you it makes sense.  My confusion was that I was considering enum to be like a variable double or dictionary.